# What is wrong with the while in this code?

Tags: arrays

I need to find the number of occurrences of an element in the array. I know that `if` will work in this problem. But what is the problem with using `while`

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exercise3{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = {1,1,1,2,3,4};
    System.out.println("The array is " + Arrays.toString(array));
    System.out.print("Please enter search element: ");
    int searchElement = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(searchElement + " appears " + getNumber(array, searchElement)+ " times"); 
}
    
    public static int getNumber(int[] array, int searchElement)
{
        int count =0;
        for (int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
            while(array[i] == searchElement) count ++;
        }
        return count;
}
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to debug. This will help you much in such cases

Comment: Have you tried running the above code? Since the precondition for the inner while loop is not changing, when `array[i]== searchElement` the while loop will not exit.

Comment: while keeps looping forever as long as its test remains true.  while (true) { System.out.println ("forever!") ; } never stops, ever.  It keeps going and going and going.

Comment: when i enter an integer which is not an element of array, it still doesn't stop

Answer (score 0):

If the number you're testing (array[i]) is equal with the number searched (searchElement) than you continue the while loop without changing "i" therefore your while loop will go on indefinitelly.

Your for loop only changes "i" once your while loop finished, but that never happens if array[i] == searchElement.

Hope that makes sense ^^